# How to check if value exists in textboxes with same name and id?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there any solution to check if value exists in multiple text-boxes with the same name and id? Actually I use text-boxes to add same values in database and I want to check if any value exists or not.please see below code.

```
function check_availability() {

  var username = $('#pats_input').val();

  $.post("load.php", {
      pats: pats
    },
    function(result) {
      if (result == 1) {
        $("#display_availability").html(username + 'Is Available');
      } else {
        $("#display_availability").html(username + 'Is Not Available');
      }
    });
}
$pats = $_POST['pats'];
$select = mysql_query("SELECT pats FROM perstat WHERE pats='$pats'") or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($select);
if ($count > 0) {
  echo 0;
} else {
  echo 1;
}

<input id="pats_input" class="pats_tb" type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
<input id="pats_input" class="pats_tb" type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
<input id="pats_input" class="pats_tb" type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
<div id="display_availability"></div>
```

Comment: ID SHOULD ALWAYS BE UNIQUE

Answer (score 2):

> Multiple inputs having same **ID** won't get you all the inputs instead it will give you the last input in Node, As ID should be unique.

You have to get values of textboxes by using the `class` and then in jquery loop through all textboxes by using `.each()` function,

**Here** is a simple demonstration.

```js
$(function(){
$("input[type='text'][class='pats_tb'][name='pats[]']").each(function(index){
  if($(this).val().length > 0) {
      console.log($(this).val());
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="pats_tb" type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
<input class="pats_tb" type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats" value="textbox2">
<input class="pats_tb" type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats" value="textbox3">
```

Comment: Thats ok, but how that will loop in php file and to check if value exists in database or not?

Comment: You should loop through your `select query` and pass `$_POST['pats'][i]` where `i` is array index, as in your case `$_POST['pats']` is an array of values.